# How to make a bar plot with two single integer values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Ideally with ggplot.

My values are:
a = 226.1405
b = 340.9898

Answer (score 1):

We could convert to a `data.frame` or `tibble` and reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` before plotting with `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
tibble(a, b) %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) + 
      geom_col()
```

-output

[image]

---

Or using `base R`, just create a named `vector` and use `barplot`

```
barplot(c(a = a, b = b))
```

#### data

```
a <-  226.1405
b <- 340.9898
```

Comment: Thank You! If possible, how would you color each bar a different color from the other? I'm able to do both of one single color only as of right now.